# Cómo hacer INSERT de un select múltiple

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Digamos que tengo un select múltiple en HTML así:

```
<select multiple name="select1[]" size="4" required>
                    <option disabled selected>Titulo</option>
                    <option value="valor1">Valor1</option>
                    <option value="valor2">Valor2</option>
                    <option value="Valor3">Valor3</option>
                    <option value="Valor4">Valor4</option>
                </select>
```

y quiero que si selecciono 2 valores, ambos se escriban en la misma columna de mi base de datos. Para hacer INSERT tengo un código así:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO datos VALUES('" . $_POST['campo1'] . "','" . $_POST['campo2'] . "','" . $_POST['campo3'] . "')";
```

y no sé cómo introducir el select ahí, he probado a poner un:

```
foreach ($_POST['select1'] as $selectedOption)
                "$selectedOption";
        }
```

y si hago print se ven todas las opciones escogidas, pero si pongo la variable de $select dentro del insert así:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO datos VALUES('" . $_POST['campo1'] . "','" . $_POST['campo2'] . "','" . $selectedOption . "')";
```

la columna sólo coge el último valor seleccionado. Evidentemente lo estoy haciendo mal, pero no seme ocurre otra forma de añadirlo al INSERT.
No sé si me he explicado ^^", gracias de antemano!

Comment: No me queda claro ¿quieres meter los valores seleccionados en el mismo campo de un mismo registro de la tabla, o en distintos registros, uno por valor seleccionado?

Comment: En el mismo registro de la tabla, imagina que hay un campo en la tabla de cuáles son tus comidas favoritas, puedes elegir varias opciones y todas esas opciones van a ese mismo campo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para guardar no un valor sino un conjunto de valores en un campo de una tabla de la base de datos, tienes que decidir primero qué formato usar. Ten en cuenta que de tu decisión dependerá no sólo cómo tienes que insertar los datos, sino también cómo recuperarlos luego.

Una opción sencilla es meter los **valores separados por coma**:

```
$valor = implode(',', $_POST['select1']);
```

Otra es **serializar el conjunto**:

```
$valor = serialize($_POST['select1']);
```

Y otra **utilizar json**:

```
$valor = json_encode($_POST['select1']);
```

Cada una de las opciones es más adecuada para según que caso, pero en general interesa valores separados por coma para conjuntos de valores muy simples, por ejemplo lista de ids, y para otras cosas, como lista de cadenas, interesa json.

Una vez obtenido el $valor, ya lo puedes insertar en el campo, pero recuerda hacerlo previniendo una posible inyección SQL y también la posible existencia de caracteres en el valor que te rompan la consulta. Puedes escapar el valor, o utilizar prepared statements.

Bueno, y otra solución, pero que ya afecta a la estructura de las tablas, es crear una tabla de posibles valores, y otra tabla que relacione esos posibles valores con tu tabla original. O prescindir de la tabla relacional y meter en el campo de tu tabla original los ids correspondientes a los valores seleccionados de la tabla de valores. Tener una tabla de valores te permite un mayor dinamismo, podrás añadir o quitar valores con facilidad. El select lo llenarías con opciones cogidas de esa tabla.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! implode es justo lo que necesitaba :D